# Why is UEFA champions league table different than usual table?

Tags: football, uefa, champions-league

UEFA Champions League [standings for group B](http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/season=2018/standings/index.html) are shown below:
[image: gb]

While the same table from [skysports.com](http://www.skysports.com/champions-league-table) and other websites like [espn](http://www.espn.in/football/table/_/league/uefa.champions), [foxsports](http://www.foxsports.com/soccer/standings?competition=7), [flashscore](http://www.flashscore.com/soccer/europe/champions-league/standings/) put PSG ahead of Bayern Munich as shown in figure below:
[image: gb-ss]

So, my question is, why is Bayern Munich ahead of PSG in UEFA table with goal difference of 3 against goal difference of 5? Is this a mistake or because of their club coefficient they are ahead or there are some other reason.

Comment: Because they are alphabetically sorted.

Comment: Agreed with @gdrt, it happens in all cases, for example in Group A FC Basel 1893 has a goal difference of -3 and is ahead of SL Benfica, which is only -1. They have a footnote stating that _Standings are provisional until all group matches have been played_.

Comment: @gdrt Well didn't think of that, was looking at goal difference only, now you mentioned it I feel stupid and this line at the bottom "Standings are provisional until all group matches have been played" may have something for table not being updated with GD.

Comment: @fedorqui Sir was writing comment beat me by 20 sec or so.

Comment: Ram: great minds think alike ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [UEFA group stage tie-breaking rules](http://www.uefa.com/MultimediaFiles/Download/Regulations/uefaorg/Regulations/02/35/87/89/2358789_DOWNLOAD.pdf#page=23):

> If two or more teams are equal on points on completion of the group
>   matches, the following criteria are applied in the order given to
>   determine their rankings:
>
> - a. higher number of points obtained in the group matches played among the teams in question;
> - [...]

But as Bayern Munich and PSG have not yet played, they are just **sorted alphabetically**. You can see that in other groups as well.

Also as you and @fedorqui already mentioned in the comments there's a footnote stating that:

> *Standings are provisional until all group matches have been played*.